# Fread read wrong number of valid bytes C

Tags: c, fread, ppm

I read two ppm images and I have a struct that stores all the informations (magic number, width, height, level of colors, and pixels). I read the pixels using fread, but the problem is that we have some test to run to see if our code is valid and can create a new ppm. One test must be not valid (not creating an image because the number of pixels is different from the size given), but my code create the image anyway, because in the fread the successful bytes read must be 83 (the condition to exit from the code is that if the number of bytes is different from the given size (width * height * 3) we return 1 and stop executing), but actually it reads 84 bytes, that is equal to the size, then it continue to execute the code, instead of blocking it, and I don't understand why. The error is after the read pixel comment.
P.s Because the code works giving two images, I give the same invalid image twice.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

struct image
{
    char *magicNumber;
    int width;
    int height;
    int level;
    uint8_t *pixels;
};

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    struct image img1;
    struct image img2;
    struct image img3;

    // Read files
    FILE *file1 = fopen(argv[1], "r");
    FILE *file2 = fopen(argv[2], "r");

    // Check files
    if (!file1 || !file2)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Error while opening the file.\n");
        return 1;
    }

    // Alloc memory for pixels array
    img1.magicNumber = (char *)malloc(3 * sizeof(char));
    img2.magicNumber = (char *)malloc(3 * sizeof(char));

    // Take magic number
    fscanf(file1, "%s", img1.magicNumber);
    fscanf(file2, "%s", img2.magicNumber);

    // Check magic number
    if (strcmp(img1.magicNumber, "P6") != 0 || strcmp(img2.magicNumber, "P6") != 0)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Invalid magic number.\n");
        return 1;
    }
    // Take width
    fscanf(file1, "%d", &img1.width);
    fscanf(file2, "%d", &img2.width);
    // Take height
    fscanf(file1, "%d", &img1.height);
    fscanf(file2, "%d", &img2.height);

    // Check size
    if (img1.width != img2.width || img1.height != img2.height)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Invalid Dimension.");
        return 1;
    }
    // Take level
    fscanf(file1, "%d", &img1.level);
    fscanf(file2, "%d", &img2.level);

    // Check level
    if (img1.level != 255 || img2.level != 255)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Invalid Level.");
        return 1;
    }
    // Alloc memory for pixels array
    img1.pixels = (uint8_t *)malloc(img1.width * img1.height * 3 * sizeof(uint8_t));
    img2.pixels = (uint8_t *)malloc(img2.width * img2.height * 3 * sizeof(uint8_t));

    // Read pixels
    size_t nrPixel1 = fread(img1.pixels, sizeof(uint8_t), img1.width * img1.height * 3, file1);
    size_t nrPixel2 = fread(img2.pixels, sizeof(uint8_t), img2.width * img2.height * 3, file2);

    // Check pixels read
    if (nrPixel1 != img1.width * img1.height * 3 || nrPixel2 != img2.width * img2.height * 3)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Invalid pixels.");
        return 1;
    }
```

Comment: Not really sure what you want us to do with this. If `fread` returns a positive number that is not the passed `size*nmemb`, then there's an error or the end of file has been reached. You are not checking for errors on both of the two `fread` calls. You have to explain better what you are trying to achieve and why do you think it doesn't work, it's really hard to tell from your wording. Also, consider the fact that the code might be right but the file content might not.

Comment: Also, side note: `fscanf(file1, "%s", img1.magicNumber);` is a clear buffer overflow waiting to happen. Use `%2s` instead (yes, 2 not 3, the terminator is automatically added) or better `fgets()`.

Comment: Mixing read methods can lead to trouble. Is there a newline remaining in the input file after the `fscanf()` (which reads text) and the `fread()` (which reads binary data)?

Comment: Also you say "in the fread the successful bytes read must be 83". How can there be 83 bytes of pixel data? 83 is a prime number.

Comment: @WeatherVane the post is very strangely worded, but I suppose OP means that `fread` reads 84 while it should read 83 (at least that's what I think after reading it four times) because they are trying to test an "invalid" image (i.e. with one less byte *I suppose*).

Comment: @MarcoBonelli I see, but still there must be a single whitespace separator between the `img1.level` text data and the pixel dump, so I can see how the read might be misaligned. One thing though: on Windows the files must be opened explictly as `"rb"` binary mode, to prevent the conversion of newlines, which could be responsible for the short data, because wherever there is `0x0D 0x0A` pixel data the `0x0D` will be skipped. And the single whitespace character must be removed too.

Comment: ... so @Elena if you are using Windows, open the files in binary mode, and also read one whitespace character from the file before reading the pixel data.

Comment: Sorry but it is a little bit difficult to explain the problem. The file content is correct. I check if the fread reads the right number of bytes in the last 5 lines, and the target is that the program enter in that condition because it is suppose to read one byte less of the expected number, because the given image "test" has been created in this way (the number of pixels (83) is less than the size (84 bytes). So I can do a general question: it is correct using fread in this way? The structure of the file image is: P6\n 1024 768\n 255\n r1g1b1r2g2b2... .

Comment: P6 is the magic number, 1024 768 the width and height, 255 the level. Between width and height there is an empty space. The problem is that is given an image with size (width * height) of 84 bytes and a list of pixels of only 83 bytes, but the fread doesn't recognise the difference between size and bytes read, and it doesn't complain, but it has to do. I want only to know if there is something with fread that can create problems, maybe something that is doesn't read.

Comment: It's hard to tell if you are reading correctly without having the exact file you are trying to read at hand, the call to `fread` looks correct to me, but you might be missing some bytes that are not read by the previous call to `fscanf` as @WeatherVane notes. You should check that.

Comment: Okay thank you. I’ll try it